# Why can't I call my jquery autocomplete after my ajax method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am trying to create a suggestions dropdown on my search (similar to google's). I want to make an ajax call which would call some php and return an array which would be the suggestions. Here's my code so far:

*Note: I have not implemented my PhP yet, so I'm just pretending that my ajax was successful and returned an array called availableTags:

```
$(function(){

    var timer;
    var availableTags;

    var getSuggestions = function() {

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'http://localhost/test.php',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(output) 
                {
                    alert('Success from ajax! ' + output);
                    availableTags = [ "Hello", "Hey"];
                }
            }
        ).done(function(data) {
            $( "#f" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
    }

    $('#f').keyup(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(getSuggestions, 300);

    });

});
```

My issue is that even though I am using a .done to load the autocomplete, it doesn't show the suggestions dropdown. I know my ajax function is working correctly because I've used it other places. Is there another way that I should be calling autocomplete?

So to clarify further - I'm looking for a way to manually load the autocomplete after my ajax. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just create it in the success function

Comment: I would just replace the `.done()` with `.success()` and combine your logic from the `success` property and `.done()` method into one place. [Like this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/za3h9bbd/).

Comment: That's what I had thought at first. But I get the same issue. the autocomplete does not show. thanks for the response

Comment: Also, if you want to have autocomplete populate before typing (depending on your use case), you will want to call `getSuggestion()` once before the `keyup` listener.

Comment: @Sam yes, that works well to populate the dropdown if there isn't any text initially. However, I want to be able to populate the autocomplete after some text has been entered. Would there be another way? The .success doesn't populate the autocomplete for the first time when text is entered. It does when I type a second time - but I believe that's just because my availableTags array is global. Thanks!

Comment: I think I may have thought of something - would it be possible to call the .autocomplete and have my ajax function inside that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is what you want ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/o2w3j1jj/)):

```
$('#f').autocomplete({
    delay: 300,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.get('http://localhost/test.php', {
            q: request.term
        }).success(function(availableTags) {
            response(availableTags);
        });
    }
});
```